# Cakephp ajax request invalid url

Tags: cakephp

i have a view page in which i have to load different views according to the option selected in a selecbox. But my problem is that the url to which ajax request is sent is not correct.
The correct path to be formatted is like this http://pc12/cakephp/users/getView but the ajax request goes to http://pc12/users/getview. What is my problem here?? My code is below:

```
jQuery('#ptype').change(function(){ 
var param = "id="+jQuery(this).val();
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/users/getView",
        data: param,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){                    
                                                                             if(data)                                        jQuery('#profile_info').html(data);                                                }
});
```

});

Comment: Solved sorry for the inconvenience

changed the url tag from "/users/getView/" to "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'getView')); ?>"

now its working fine

Answer (score 2):

write complete address:

```
/AppName/Controller/Action/
```

you can use firebug for debug any ajax requests. it's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the first front slash as I think.
url: "**/**users/getView",

in url: remove the first front slash(/) before users and it will work fine. I am using the same format without any problem. It will be like. 
url: "users/getView",

it is easy and clear to use than your replacement: Html->url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'getView')); ?>